# Can I create the installer class in the setup project instead of the windows form project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project

I created a separated visual studio installer project from the windows form project and gave it the exe and all needed files in the file system --> application folder, but I need to add installer class to do some extra actions in the installation, my problem that I don't want to create it in the windows form that contains the project I need to separate it from the windows form and create it in different place then link it to the exe of the windows form somehow
the default installer class that I am talking about as below

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class InstallerInterface : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public InstallerInterface()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }
}
```

Can I put it in different place from the windows form and link it to the exe file that contains the application in the visual studio installer project, I asked because all the online resources create it in the windows form that contains the application.

Comment: Is this just intellectual curiosity or is there a *reason* you don't want to do it the same way most people do? It's usually quite convenient because the sorts of things you'll want to use an installer class for (e.g. creating an event source) are also the sort of things that your program will interact with regularly (creating events) and so there's often common code (or at least, constants).

Comment: I just want to separate the installer class from the windows form and put it in the setup project because I didn't create windows form and the setup project in the same Solution explorer I create it in different solutions so I need it to be with the setup project Solution explorer instead of the main application solution explorer

Comment: You jump from "separate solutions" to "it needs to be in the setup project solution". That's not a required leap. Anyhow, the setup project isn't designed to compile C# code, so the simple answer is no you can't put it in there. You could put it in a separate class library project (in either solution) but there's no *requirement* that it be in a project that's part of the setup project's solution.